# Why do not keep color cells from gridview after sorting? vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have code for color my cell if value from cell is "Yes"

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    LBL_Status.Text = Nothing

    Dim Qty As Double = 0
    Dim CostCategory As Double = 0

    If GridView1.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        For x As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For y As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1

                If y = "9" Then
                    Qty = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(9).Text)
                End If

                If y = "13" Then
                    CostCategory = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(13).Text)
                End If

                If y = "14" Then
                    GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(14).Text = Qty * CostCategory
                End If

                If GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text = "Yes" Then
                    GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen

                ElseIf GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text = "No" Then
                    GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed

                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        LBL_Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        LBL_Status.Text = "No data find for your search !"
    End If

End Sub
```

I have select from GridView proprieties "Enable Sorting", but when i sort by one column, colors cells disappears.

How do i keep color cell?

Comment: When you are executing this code?

Comment: YEs, this code is good, my cell are red and green, but when i click on column in table for sorting, my colors disappears.

Comment: No you didn't get my point I am asking when this code is getting executed? I mean in `Page_Load` or any other event.

Comment: Is in page load, i don't put all cod

Comment: This is not the right place to do this. You should do this in _RowDataBound_ event of gridview. Where you are binding your gridview  then?